# BufferedImage ARGB transparency only works when drawn image is moving

Tags: java

I just converted my project from RGB to ARGB. The opaque objects all draw fine but when I add transparency to the 'color' (set by hex: 0x55ff0000) of any drawn object they only draw the correct transparency if they are moving.

**The problem: Alpha drawn objects seem to 'stack' up every step until they are opaque.**

While they remain stationary they quickly become more and more opaque over a second. I'm still learning how the BufferedImages work but I believe i'm missing a piece of code that I require for ARGB instead of just RGB.

```
public class Window
{
private JFrame frame;
static BufferedImage image;
private Canvas canvas;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

public Window(Game game)
    {
    image = new BufferedImage(game.getWidth(), game.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    canvas = new Canvas();
    Dimension s = new Dimension(game.getWidth() * game.getScale(),game.getHeight() * game.getScale());
    canvas.setPreferredSize(s);
    canvas.setMaximumSize(s);
    canvas.setMinimumSize(s);

    frame = new JFrame(game.getName());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Add canvas to the frame
    frame.pack(); //Set frame to size of canvas
    //Removed some other 'frame.xxx' lines of code which don't assist the problem.
    //frame.repaint();

    canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
    bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

public void update()
    {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), null); //Draws everything to buffer strategy.
    bs.show(); //Draws from buffer strategy to canvas.
    }

public JFrame getFrame()
    {
    return frame;
    }
}
```

The only other code I changed to convert to ARGB was this which was 0 beforehand:

```
    public Renderer(Game game)
    {
    display = ((DataBufferInt)game.getWindow().getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); //Displays all the data drawn to screen.
    }

public void clear()
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < display.length; i++) //Loops through the screens pixels and clears them.
        {
        display[i] = 0xff000000; //Clear the screen with opaque black.
        }
    }
```

When I change display[i] = 0xff000000; to 0x0f000000 the problem is exacerbated and it has a slow motion effect - but i'm not sure how to increase an already full alpha of "ff" higher.

**I make a GIF of the problem, however it's distorted a fair bit: https://giphy.com/gifs/java-RF6stHznOiR9e
Note how it fades back in after I stop moving, and where the circle overlaps it stays opaque.**

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "image is moving" and "over a second"?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is related to the fact that you're not clearing the `Graphics` context of the `BufferStrategy`, because it will still be holding what ever was last painted to it when you try and update it

Comment: You also don't seem to making proper use of the `BufferStrategy `, have a look at the [JavaDocs for `Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) for a basic example

Comment: Usagi - By moving I mean, as long as it's not stationary, x, y is moving any direction or it's being drawn at different positions every step. By over a second I mean - every step the drawn transparent line becomes more opaque and by the time a second has elapsed it's fully opaque.

Comment: Mad Programmer - That could possibly be the problem, however I believed I was clearing it with display[i] line which worked fine for RGB, without this line all the drawings just stack up on top of each other. I'll have a look there and read over that article. I was following this from a tutorial back when I added the BS so I could have missed something.